# Can I load a new page when someone click on close button on browser?

Tags: javascript, html

Can I do it? If yes, than how? I tried unonload, but that works only when I click on an url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function(){
      window.open('url') 
  }
```

Comment: This one is working on Firefox and Chrome, but don't work on Opera. Do you know how to make it to work for opera?

Comment: it will not work on opera .. [read this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683221/cross-browser-onunload-and-onbeforeunload-particularly-opera-11)